# Logarithmic option on network profile reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph, network-profile

The discrepancy between my reputation on one SO network site and that on my other sites makes it difficult to compare all of them on one linearly-scaled graph:

[image: Linear Reputation Plot]

Could we get a logarithmic scale option to make it easier to compare lower and higher reputation sites on one graph?

It'd also be good to see a nice straight line indicating exponential reputation growth should that ever occur.

Comment: You _can_ turn off a specific site by clicking it.

Comment: @Oded I'm aware of that, and of being able to zoom in on an area, but I'd like to be able to make some meaningful comparison between my big site and my little sites all at once.

Answer (score 1):

This seems unwarranted to me.

Because rep is capped, the range of values is fairly narrow. If you're only making a trickle of points, I think it's reasonable to leave it showing as that.

Who cares if you see a noticable sawtooth on a graph of points with daily scores of 10, 20,10, 20? It might as well be a flat line - it's practically no points anyway